# how to compare and extract 2 columns PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to extract colums that different in fruit colum but have a same value in fruit_id colum. how's the query?
please help

| fruit | fruit_id |
| --- | --- |
| apple | a1 |
| banana | b1 |
| citrus | c1 |
| manggo | a1 |
| orange | c1 |

I expected the result is :

| fruit | fruit_id |
| --- | --- |
| apple | a1 |
| manggo | a1 |
| citrus | c1 |
| orange | c1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT f1.fruit, f1.fruit_id
FROM fruits f1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM fruits f2
    WHERE f2.fruit_id = f1.fruit_id AND
          f2.fruit <> f1.fruit
);
```